# App doesn't show up on the Android Market

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-market-filtering

We've upgraded yesterday our App (easy.go) on the Android Market and after that we have got several messages from HTC Tattoo and Sony Ericsson XPeria mini users, that they can't see application on Android Market.

We are not you using Copy Protection when uploading to the market, so I guess, it couldn't be a problem.

The first assumption is that the problem was beacause of small screens. I took a look in manifest.xml. There is written:

```
<supports-screens
   android:largeScreens="true"
   android:normalScreens="true"
   android:smallScreens="true"
   android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

And here are all permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>
```

Any suggestions?!

There are some big images with resolution 320x480 and no alternatives for them in resolution 240x320. Could it be the problem?!

Is there some preview before upgrading an app to know for which devices it will be invisible on the market?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess, I know now the answer:
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html#manifest-filters

If I understood it right

> **Example 1** The manifest declares *`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3">`*
>   and does not does not include a
>   *`<supports-screens>`* element. Result:
>   Android Market will not show the app
>   to a user of a small-screen device,
>   but will show it to users of normal
>   and large-screen devices, users,
>   unless other filters apply.
>
> **Example 2** The manifest declares 
>   *`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4">`* and does
>   not include a *`<supports-screens>`*
>   element. Result: Android Market will
>   show the app to users on all devices,
>   unless other filters apply.

then **`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>`** should be replaced with **`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>`**

Comment: Yes, that was it. We've published new version our app today and now it's also visible for small smartphone users

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at market filters rules if it's not already done, maybe it could help you:
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html

Comment: In your case you specify the supports-screen, so it should appear in the market if your <supports-screen> tag is placed inside <manifest> and outside <application> tag.

Comment: Be sure you didn't lock the country of those users on the android market interface.