# My Apps don't appear on the top free list on the android market

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, galaxy-tab

Hey i have few apps in the top places on some list (music\games) on the android market but when i look with galaxy tab 10 i they don't appear.

does anyone know what is the reason? should i need to add somthing in my manifest?

tnx

Comment: possible duplicate of [App doesn't show up on the Android Market](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153208/app-doesnt-show-up-on-the-android-market)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Android Market indeed employs a filtering mechanism that (among other things like SIM card country) inspects your application Manifest and decides whether or not to make your application available to certain devices. You could, for instance, decide to make your application only available to devices that specify a certain screen size.

Have a look at the [Android Compatibility](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html) docs, particularly the Market Filters bit.